# Why DataTables methods don't work on table?

Tags: javascript, datatables

Doing my first step in web developing and currently learning DataTables.

The QuickStart guide on DataTables provides an example of function:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
   $('#table_id').DataTable();
 });
```

What I am confused about is that when I slightly change this function it doesn't work:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    var table = document.getElementsByTagName("table");
    table.DataTable();
 });
```

In the console I am getting an error that 'table' doesn't have DataTable function.

However, this variation of function works fine:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $(document.getElementsByTagName("table")).DataTable();
});
```

I would really appreciate an explanation.

Comment: Please select an answer if found useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Datatables is plugin for jQuery. That is why you need to use jQuery object of your element.

> The $ symbol used in jQuery is a selector function which takes CSS style selectors as input and returns DOM references (in jQuery object form), which can be used to manipulate DOM properties.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the API incorrectly `.Datatable()`  is not a member of that target `DOM Node` So your change does not work

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what js you have imported but it seems that your imported js does not contain that method. if you haven't imported library yet, you may need to add [jquery Ui](https://datatables.net/extensions/scroller/examples/styling/jqueryui.html) to use it datatable.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        ajax:           "../data/2500.txt",
        deferRender:    true,
        scrollY:        200,
        scrollCollapse: true,
        scroller:       true
    } );
} );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var table = document.getElementsByTagName("table");
```

getElementByTagName gives you element that is where you did mistake. yau have set of array  in your `var table`
  and othe thing you are not writing selector properly again.

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    var table = document.getElementsByTagName("table");
    $(table).DataTable();
 });
```